# SQL Server Service Broker system error -9616, when can it happen?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, service-broker

I have a scenario in one of my Service Broker conversation configurations, which looks like this:

- one message type, which is sent by initiator only (VALIDATION = WELL_FORMED_XML, **no XSD**)
- one contract with this message type
- both deployed on the initiator and target side (remote machines)

Occasionally I find Service Broker system error messages in the **target queue** like this:

```
<Error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/Error"><Code>-9616</Code><Description>A message of type 'here_is_the_name' was received and failed XML validation.  XML parsing: line 1, character 547, illegal xml character This occurred in the message with Conversation ID 'here_is_the_guid', Initiator: 1, and Message sequence number: 0.</Description</Error>
```

I looked at Remus Rusanu's blog [post](http://rusanu.com/2007/12/03/resending-messages/) and he states that:

> This system error is sent to a conversation that has sent a message type marked as conforming to a certain XML schema but the payload has failed to pass the XML validation for the said schema

In my case there is no XML schema involved and I was trying to reproduce this case in my dev env using the same SQL Server versions and I was unable to do it.

---

I would like to know is it possible to receive this system error message although I'm not using XSD schema ? If so, when can it happen, what is the scenario where Service Broker generates error like above?

The message clearly says "XML parsing: line 1, character 547, illegal xml character" so in my opinion it has nothing to do with the schema validation.
Can it be that the transport level is encountering some problems (TCP errors) and that is why Service Broker is generating this error message ?

Answer (score 2):

Message validation occurs on enqueue the message in the target queue, not on SEND. Message type validation (NONE, XML, XDS) is provided to protect your application. Validating during SEND is not enough, as a malicious application can send a message w/o using Service Broker ( a wire protocol simulator). Since validation during enqueue is mandatory, adding validation during SEND would add CPU burden for little value.

So what that means is the your SEND side application is sending invalid XML, and this gets caught on the target side. The wording on my blog is poorly chosen, I should had been more explicit that the validation can fail a schema (if specified) or it can fail the [well formed](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-wellformed) XML test.

Can you post the message body you're sending?

Comment: Thanks Remus for your reply. I understand the first part and I'm aware that SSB is working in this way, validation on enqueue makes perfect sense. 
The second part confused me a bit, because I always knew (this was presented on Your blog about Fire and Forget pattern for example) 
that if initiator sends a message and the target does not accept it because eg. it's not valid XML, the **target will send an error** message to the initiator. 
This is exactly what I observed many times, but in the case I described in this issue the error msg was in the target queue and this is one-way msg exchange.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to post the message body as this happens in our production and unfortunately initially the EAI application that uses Service Broker underneath was deployed with Fire and Forget pattern (yes, I know it's very bad, I'm trying to influence some people to change that). So in my case even turning retention has no use.

Comment: The message being in the target queue means that there is an (invalid XML) reply from the target that gets rejected by the initiator. Double-check the target code. Monitor [Broker:Conversation Event Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188678.aspx).

Comment: I deployed my production conversation configuration on dev and tested what you suggested. As this is one-way message exchange and, as described above, the contract says that only initiator can send a message, while trying to reply from the target I got: Msg 8434, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The message cannot be sent because the message type 'msg_type_name' is marked SENT BY INTITIATOR in the contract, however this service is a Target.